# Radiator gushes fluid but car doesn't overheat

Tags: coolant, holden

We have a Holden 2004 exe. On short distances, the car runs fine. However, driving far we've noticed water gushing out from the right front side of the car where the reservoir is. The temperature gauge does not change though. When we got home the car was boiling in the radiator.

We had taken it to two different mechanics one said it was because of set plug in the engine and another one (trustworthy) said he cannot tell us the problem because the car would not boil again in front of him so he can not tell what it could be.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Has either of the mechanics conducted a cooling system pressure test? If the system is not holding pressure it would allow it to boil. The solution could be as simple as replacing the radiator cap.

Comment: Agree with @CharlieRB, and think thats good enough to be posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3):

A cooling system pressure test should be conducted. If the system is not holding pressure it will boil too readily. The solution could be as simple as replacing the radiator cap.